# Create the type of Box<T>

Tags: rust

I have this code, but it gives me a compile error. How to create an instance of the `Test` struct in order to fix the error?

```rust
enum Fruit {
    Apple(String),
    Banana(String),
}

struct Test {
    A: Box<Fruit>,
}

fn main() {
    let name = String::from("apple");
    let test = Test {
        A: Box::<Fruit::Apple("apple".to_string())>, 
    };
    // match test {
    //     Box
    // }
}
```

```
error: unmatched angle bracket
  --> src/main.rs:13:17
   |
13 |         A: Box::<Fruit::Apple("apple".to_string())>, 
   |                 ^ help: remove extra angle bracket

error: expected type, found `"apple"`
  --> src/main.rs:13:31
   |
12 |     let test = Test {
   |                ---- while parsing this struct
13 |         A: Box::<Fruit::Apple("apple".to_string())>, 
   |                               ^^^^^^^ expected type
```

Comment: Please see The Rust Programming language book, section 15.1 on [Using Box<T> to Store Data on the Heap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch15-01-box.html), and the standard documentation of [`std::boxed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/index.html), they explain the subject rather well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may help you.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Fruit {
    Apple(String),
    Banana(String),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test {
    A: Box<Fruit>,
}

fn main() {
    let test = Test {
        A: Box::new(Fruit::Apple("apple".to_string())),
    };
    println!("{:?}", test)
}
```

Comment: As both of you are new contributors. Would you mind trying to expand and explain to him what the error is. What was the solution and point him to the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

`Box<T>` is the generic representation of a `Box` containing `T`. You use this when specifying the type of a value, such as a struct field or return type:

```rust
struct Test {
    A: Box<Fruit>,
}

fn test() -> Box<Fruit> {}
```

To actually allocate memory on the heap and create a `Box` that stores `T`, you have to use the `Box::new()` function:

```rust
let test = Test {
    A: Box::new(Fruit::Apple("apple".to_string())),
};
```